# How do I verify and query my transaction? (Web3.py + Infura + Remix)

Tags: remix, web3.py, infura, ethereum-classic

I've used buildTransaction() (which works at Contract.transact()) and I can see my transaction has taken place.

(https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xebcd3e42340688087162bbf4359390de3d77c2b43d8a4683277651b462117a81)

While doing so, I've used the abi and bin contents for calling BuildTransaction, i.e. contract_ = w3.eth.contract(abi=filecontents,bytecode=bincontents)

```
transaction = {
'to': '0x6c8B815c51D8B84324804167DD6A1a5623407a3F',
'value': 0,
'gas': 4700000,
'gasPrice': w3.eth.gasPrice,
'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)
}

tx = contract_.buildTransaction(transaction).setGreeting('Omid')
signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, pk)
final = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
```

Solidity contract

```
contract Greeter {
string public greeting;

function Greeter() public {
  greeting = 'Hello';
}

function setGreeting(string _greeting) public {
  greeting = _greeting;
}

function greet() view public returns (string) {
  return greeting;
}
```

How can I check that the value I've tried setting through setGreeting has been updated in my contract constructor (whose address I haven't mentioned for calling setGreeting above)?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is going to sound a little stupid, but it looks like you just copied that smart contract form another source?

```
contract Greeter {
string public greeting;

function Greeter() public {
  greeting = 'Hello';
}

function setGreeting(string _greeting) public {
  greeting = _greeting;
}

function greet() view public returns (string) {
  return greeting;
}
```

So within the smart contract and even in remix where you deployed the contract you can view the contract. Just call the greet and/or greeting public getter. Honestly, you don't need both. As for doing it in web3.py, that's a different issue, but should be indicated in the documentation :)

[image: Remix Contract]

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#contract-deployment-example

Equivalently in web3, the following commands are useful, now you could skip the creation process and just input the address of the deployed contract. You still need the abi of the compiled contract tho.

```
# Create the contract instance with the newly-deployed address
greeter = w3.eth.contract(
    address=tx_receipt.contractAddress,
    abi=contract_interface['abi'],
)

# Display the default greeting from the contract
print('Default contract greeting: {}'.format(
    greeter.functions.greet().call()
))
```

In particular,

```
greeter.functions.greet().call()
```

will return hello

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes, it does work with the remix ide.

Do you know how do they decide the value of 'to' when calling a function/transaction? Is that something we have to manually declare when making such transactions on web3.py? Please let me know how to do the same on web3.py?

Comment: In the example, https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#contract-deployment-example, it deploys a contract and then stores its abi. In web3, the to field is equvialently the contract address + the method you want to call.

Comment: please upvote if my answer was helpful :)

Comment: I'm trying to understand how can I verify my updated value through web3.py, i.e. how do I get the value 'Omid' back?

Comment: After the updating is returned, you can call greeter.functions.greet().call() and it will return greeting.

Comment: Nope, it still returns 'Hello' from greeter.functions.greet().call(). 

Just to summarise the steps of flow: 
1) Create abi, bin and call contract
2) Create a transaction and use Settransaction 
3) Use the deployed contract to call the function to check if the value has updated

Comment: This also points to the core of my question as to how does greeter as a contract recognise different 'to' and 'from' transaction updates? I.e., since we did not use the contract's address when updating the value, how does the contract get the updated value on calling it using its address?